# How often do you use 'nowadays' vs 'these days' in your dialect?

Tags: british-english, dialects, north-american-english, australian-english, new-zealand-english

I would say that in South Africa, *nowadays* is rather quaint; something that perhaps Boomers and older or second language speakers would use. Unfortunately, I cautioned a student nearly a year ago against using it for this reason and I'm now doubting my advice.

Anecdotal confirmation from my career English teaching Boomer mother is that *nowadays* has fallen out of use in South Africa and googling ***"south africa" nowadays*** returns zero results including *nowadays* being used explicitly with the synonym ***today*** being substituted in the results. Saffers would probably use either *these days* or *today* in that order of preference instead of *nowadays*.

So my question is, how prevalent is *nowadays* amongst Yanks, Brits, Canucks, Aussies, and Kiwis? I'm seeing it all over the internet now because my attention is on it and it makes me cringe that I perhaps gave the wrong advice.

Comment: I would find neither usage remarkable, here in the US.  Not all that common, but not unusual.

Comment: _These days_ is a spondee with two stressed syllables; _nowadays_ is an anapest with two unstressed and one stressed. Anapests take longer to say; spondees take more energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nowadays%2Cthese%20days&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnowadays%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20days%3B%2Cc0) shows "nowadays" and "these days" are about equal in British English, while "nowadays" is about half as common as "these days" in American English.

I am American, and I would *not* say that "nowadays" is quaint.

Comment: Yeah, it's just more casual/informal.

Comment: I am British, and I would not find 'nowadays' at all quaint. I would, however, find 'Boomer' annoying.

Comment: There is another word like Boomer, "gammon", which younger British people use pejoratively about older generations.

Answer (score 0):

As a British native from Northern England, I don't find "nowadays" at all quaint or antiquated. Clearly, Americans and Saffers have a different feel.

I've learned three new words today:
Saffer,
spondee,
anapest.